# Update SQL rows cutting down to 14 characters

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column with 20 characters in 69000 entries, is it possible to update each row cutting it down to the first 14 characters, i've done 'left' to select the data but how would i go about updating each row in the column?

```
SELECT LEFT(s_model_description, 14) AS Expr1 FROM s_service_repairs
```

Cheers.

Comment: . . Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
update s_service_repairs
set s_model_description = LEFT(s_model_description, 14)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update [your_table_name]
set [column_name_you_want_to_update] = left([column_name_you_want_to_update],14)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something about the `Expr14` makes me think of SQL Server, so this answer is most appropriate for that database.

I would suggest two things.  First, update the values:

```
update s_service_repairs
    set s_model_description = left(s_model_description, 14);
```

Then alter the table so only 14 characters are allowed:

```
alter s_service_repairs alter s_model_description varchar(14);
```

This will limit the number of values allowed into the column in the future.

If the first 14 characters mean something, but you might want the full name, you can add a computed column.

```
alter s_service_repairs add s_model_description_14 as ( left(s_model_description, 14) );
```